# OpenSearch Anomaly Detector - Cannot preview historical data

Tags: amazon-web-services, anomaly-detection, amazon-opensearch

I have roughly 1400 logs in my OpenSearch index. Roughly 835 are historical, and now I am continuously ingesting using Kinesis Firehose. [Rows in my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjsbK.png)

When I am creating a detector I am not able to preview this data, I get the following alert:

"No sample anomaly result generated. Please check the detector interval and make sure you have >400 data points during the preview date range."[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BXyR.png)

My detector interval- is 3 minutes, window delay- is 1 minute, and window size- is 8.

My data is in the following format, [Log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4vU2.png)

Historical data can also be found here: [Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/eashankaushik/logsanomalydetection)

I did not get an anomaly here:

[Feature Breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfF8C.png)

I also have a template for my index:

```
PUT  _template/logs
{
    "index_patterns": ["logs*"],
    "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
       "properties": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_second"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This is the first time I am working with anomaly detectors not sure if this is expected or I am missing something.

Comment: any luck? I'm on the same spot